# Error with function resolution while dynamically loading a .o object from Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing a tool for which I want a modular architecture. By that I mean that the users would be able to write down a list of the modules they want to be loaded at start-up and my tool would be loading the corresponding `.o` for me.

Here is the code I managed to write up until now:

```
module Core where

import           Data.Monoid                  ((<>))
import           Data.Text                    (pack, unpack)
import           System.Directory             (getHomeDirectory)
import           System.Plugins.DynamicLoader

loadPlugins :: [Text] -> IO ()
loadPlugins plugins = do
  home <- getHomeDirectory
  -- addDLL "/home/tchoutri/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/base-4.11.1.0/libHSbase-4.11.1.0-ghc8.4.3.so"
  let paths = fmap (\x -> (pack home) <> "/.local/lib/polynot/polynot-" <> x <> ".o") plugins
  forM_ paths $ \path -> load path
 where
    load path = do
      m <- loadModuleFromPath (unpack path) (Just $ unpack path)
      resolveFunctions
      loadFunction m "runPlugin"
```

The plugin I'm trying to load at this moment is very simple:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Polynot.Plugin.Twitter where

runPlugin :: IO ()
runPlugin = putStrLn "[Twitter] 'sup"
```

It is compiled with `stack ghc -- --make -dynamic -fPIC -O3 twitter.hs`. It is then renamed `polynot-twitter.o`, in `~/.local/lib/polynot/`.

The compilation goes well, and when I run `stack exec -- polynot`, I get this error:

`polynot: user error (Unable to get qualified name from: /home/tchoutri/.local/lib/polynot/polynot-twitter.o)`

A quick google search showed me that the only instances of this error appear in the source code. :/

Moreover, I use the git version of dynamic-loader.

(I may be mistaken about my choice for a modular architecture, I totally accept that. If you have a better approach I could use, you can totally comment on it :)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to duplicate your error.  I get a `Prelude.head: empty list` exception instead.

However, my guess is that it has to do with the functions in `dynamic-loader` expecting to load modules from a hierarchical directory structure that matches the module hierarchy.

In a nutshell, if I store the plugin in:

```
~/.local/lib/polynot/Polynot/Plugin/Twitter.o
```

and use `loadModule` like so:

```
loadModule "Polynot.Plugin.Twitter" 
           (Just "/home/buhr/.local/lib/polynot") (Just "o")
```

then it works okay for me.

The `Main.hs` I used was the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Monad                (forM_)
import           Data.Monoid                  ((<>))
import           Data.Text                    (pack, unpack, Text)
import           System.Directory             (getHomeDirectory)
import           System.Plugins.DynamicLoader

loadPlugins :: [Text] -> IO ()
loadPlugins plugins = do
  home <- getHomeDirectory
  let basedir = (pack home) <> "/.local/lib/polynot"
  forM_ plugins (load basedir)
 where
    load dir plugin = do
      m <- loadModule (unpack plugin) (Just $ unpack dir) (Just "o")
      resolveFunctions
      entry <- loadFunction m "runPlugin"
      entry

main = do
  putStrLn "starting!"
  loadPlugins ["Polynot.Plugin.Twitter"]
  putStrLn "done!"
```

Comment: Hi! I think that's because I use Relude, which is an alternative prelude that works over `NonEmpty a` instead of `[a]`.

Furthermore, is there any library you'd have installed on your system that may help symbol resolution? After running your code, I get

`starting!'polynot: /home/tchoutri/.local/lib/polynot/Polynot/Plugin/Twitter.o: unknown symbol 'ghczmprim_GHCziCString_unpackCStringzh_info'
polynot: user error (Unable to resolve functions!)`

Comment: I was able to resolve a similar issue by compiling the main program (i.e., the one doing the load) with `-dynamic` as well.  More generally, you might need to do some `addDLL` calls to get symbols properly resolved.

Comment: Thank you so much! Are you talking about the `addDLL "/home/tchoutri/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/base-4.11.1.0/libHSbase-4.11.1.0-ghc8.4.3.so"` call in particular or do you have others in mind?